# hive always reduce on 0%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

i have use hive to analysis data
I create table and load local file to hive
when i Run hiveql on hive

`select sum(qlog_test.contlength) from qlog_test where qlog_test.area='HK' limit 10;`

it stuck at map 100% reduce 0%

`2012-12-08 21:39:28,349 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:29,370 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:30,385 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:31,401 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:32,413 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:33,423 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 29.72 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:34,434 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:35,445 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:36,455 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:37,466 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:38,485 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:39,503 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:40,515 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:41,526 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:42,536 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:43,551 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:44,561 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:45,570 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:46,580 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:47,589 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:48,603 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:49,619 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:50,632 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:51,647 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:52,661 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:53,675 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:54,686 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:55,698 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:56,710 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:57,720 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:58,732 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:39:59,747 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:00,758 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:01,768 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:02,777 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:03,786 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:04,795 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:05,804 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:06,815 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:07,828 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:08,840 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:09,854 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec
2012-12-08 21:40:10,867 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 35.89 sec`

this is my hadoop node detail

[image]

and this is the map/reduce job detail
[image]

Comment: Are there available slots for a reducer to run?

Comment: how to see if reducer slots is available?

Comment: It's show in the top level of the job tracker web ui

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Make sure you look the reducer logs. Referring to your screenshot, click on the 1 in the reduce row and track down the file that is logging all the data. Then, click on All, and take a look at what's causing the problem. The problem I had was that there was an IP misconfiguration, and so the mapper and the reducer could not communicate. Restarting my system helped. Edit your question to include what the reduce log says and maybe we can help you further.